# F# function to return either of multiple types

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

My scenario is a DSL where user enters text to execute. text can either be numeric operation or a relation operation(returns boolean) on a string or number.
in user input there can be either constant value or a variable (where variable value has to be get from another source/dictionary and used in operation)

example (number operation)

```
(1 + 2)
(@variableName@ + 2)   //returns int
```

relation operation example

```
(@countryname@ in {abc,def,ghi}) //returns bool over variable with string value
(3 > 5) //returns bool over int
(@VariableInt@ > 5) // bool over variable having int value
```

I have DU to represent by Number

```
type NumberExpression
| VariableName of string  //variable name
|Constant of int
| Add of NumberExpression * expression

type RelationExpression
 | Boolean of bool
 | GT of NumberExpression * NumberExpression 
 | In of NumberExpression * string list
```

for interpreting my expression/variable I have something like, **from here in case of variableName I want to return either string or int** so my RelationExpression|In can get string value

```
let rec Interpret input =
 match input with
 | VariableName(name) -> 
     let stringvalue,datatype = datadictionary.[name] //assume value is from map. I need to do typecase and either return string or int here???
 | Constant(value) ->value
```

for number operations on variable works for relationexpression as it return type of variable is int. Now I have to handle return type for variables returning string values.
 How can my NumberExpression|variable return either int/string

I can try to create a discriminator union of float and string, and my function will return this new Discriminator union, but now problem is all by default float operations will not be valid on my new discriminator union (which even though is float value).

```
type myResultType = 
   | Number of float
   | StringItem of string

//assume function has some logic to return either float/string
let myFunction input = 
  match input with
  | "F" -> input |> Number
  | "S" -> input |> StringItem

// assume some logic to consume float number returned by my function. 
let finalValue = (10.0) + (myFunction "200F")
```

eventhough my function returns internal Float, but its new union type and doesn't have + operator. so approach of using DU to return either of type will not work for me. How to handle this?

Comment: Can't be done without a du whilst maintaining type safety, or a lot of effort to add operators to the du

Comment: This is a logical problem rather than technical. There are ways to make it work but it will fail at runtime when returning strings, so we're back to question why use a DU if it doesn't provide type safety. Can you give more details of your specific scenario, looks that something is wrong with the design.

Comment: Now that I see your context, I'd say that you should *evaluate the variable* before using it in an operation. So: `let eval (thing:myResultType) = match thing with Number n -> n | StringItem name -> lookupValueOf name`. The `lookupValueOf` function takes a string and returns a float. Then you don't have to mess with redefining operators: you just turn those strings into floats before you calculate the value (because it's an error for the user to type a name that they haven't yet defined, right?)

Comment: my variable can hold either string/int value. now my lookupValueof function has to either return a float/string. my lookup source is a dictionary whose value is Tuple("stringvalue"* "DataType"). Based on datatype, I have to typecast stringvalue to that datatype.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you could do it. I'll show the code first, then explain it:

```
type myResultType = 
   | Number of float
   | StringItem of string

// I fleshed out your `myFunction` example so it actually compiles
let myFunction (input:string) = 
  match input.[input.Length-1] with
  | 'F' -> input.[0..input.Length-2] |> float |> Number
  | 'S' -> input.[0..input.Length-2] |> StringItem

// Use this one for unary operators (no examples given here)
let floatOp op result =
    match result with
    | Number n -> op n |> Number
    | anythingElse -> anythingElse

// Use this one to define operators where the "real" float is the first operand
let floatOp2 op floatArg result =
    match result with
    | Number n -> op floatArg n |> Number
    | anythingElse -> anythingElse

// Use this one to define operators where the "real" float is the second operand
let floatOp2' op result floatArg =
    match result with
    | Number n -> op n floatArg |> Number
    | anythingElse -> anythingElse

let (+.) = floatOp2 (+)
let ( *. ) = floatOp2 (*)   // Spaces needed so this doesn't look like a comment
// etc.
let (.+) = floatOp2' (+)
// etc.

let finalValue = (10.0) +. (myFunction "200F")
let finalValue' = (myFunction "200F") .+ 10.0
```

You can't redefine the existing `+` operator, but you *can* create your own operator that will operate on `Number` cases (and do nothing if your result type is a `StringItem` case). Since the common code for all those operators looks pretty much the same, I extracted it into its own function. Then you could define the `-.`, `/.`, etc. operators in much the same way as you've defined the `+.` and `*.` operators.

Note how I put spaces inside the parentheses when defining the `*.` operator. This is necessary any time you're defining a custom operator that starts (or ends) with the `*` character. Otherwise the `(*` or `*)` looks like the start of a comment. E.g., `let (*!*) arg1 arg2 = ...` looks to the F# parser like a comment containing a single exclamation mark, and it thinks you're defining a function named `arg1` that takes a single parameter named `arg2`. However, `let ( *!* ) arg1 arg2 = ...` will be correctly parsed as defining an operator `*!*` that takes two arguments.

Comment: However, I mostly agree with @Gustavo's comment: this is probably a sign of a design decision that should be made differently. If you find that you want to return two different types from your function, you might need to rethink that function's design. WHY do you want it to return two different types? Is that a fundamental part of the data model, or is it accidental complexity?

Comment: thanks all for inputs, I have modified question to give more context on my problem